# ROS DEPRECATED get_transforms_vec

Tags: ros-groovy, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to port scene_label_3D package at http://www.ros.org/wiki/cornell-ros-pkg, developed in a ROS diamondback to groovy. I was able to modify other bt objects in the package according to the bullet migration guide, but I am stuck in -

The problem is, that I want to find the transformation matrix by extracting the rotation and translation matrix from a tf::tfMessageConstPtr type object. This class has been changed and does not contain any get_transforms_vec function anymore. So my real question now is

How can I find a quaternion from the tf::tfMessageConstPtr object which is initialized as
tf::tfMessageConstPtr tf_ptr = mtf.instantiate<tf::tfMessage > ();
because my transformation data is contained inside a bag file.
and assign it to a tf::transform type object?

The full code snippet is given below:

```
     tf::Transform final_tft;

    BOOST_FOREACH(rosbag::MessageInstance const mtf, view_tf)
    {
        cout<<"Inside boost foreach"<<endl;
        tf::tfMessageConstPtr tf_ptr = mtf.instantiate<tf::tfMessage > ();
        assert(tf_ptr != NULL);
        std::vector<geometry_msgs::TransformStamped> bt;
        tf_ptr->get_transforms_vec(bt);
        tf::Transform tft(getQuaternion(bt[0].transform.rotation), getVector3(bt[0].transform.translation));

            tf_count++;
            final_tft = tft;
    }
```

And I receive the error saying that there is no get_transforms_vec function.
I am struggling to solve this problem since many days. I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Akshay

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61251/ros-deprecated-get_transforms_vec/) by [Robetraks](https://answers.ros.org/users/4427/robetraks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-04-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [olmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/11421/olmin/) on 2014-01-29**:
Same problem, could you solved it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Akshay,

I have been working on it. What I found the solution is,

Change the whole section with the bellow section, it will works properly. Note: I am working on ROS groovy.

TransformG readTranform(const string & filename) {

```
boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> mat(4,4);

ifstream file((char*) filename.c_str(), ifstream::in);

string line;

int row = 0;

while(getline(file,line)){

    string e1;

    stringstream lineStream(line);

    int col = 0;

    while(getline(lineStream, e1, ',')){

        mat(row,col) = atof(e1.c_str());

            col +=1;

    }

    row += 1;

}

TransformG transG(mat);

return transG;
```

}

Have a look and let me know, If you still face any issue. Remember you might need to sort of changes in some other file too.

---

Originally posted by [vibek4989](https://answers.ros.org/users/18952/vibek4989/) with karma: 16 on 2015-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0